# React Redux - moving a function to the container from a stateless component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

Novice.

I have refactored an address component into two. One is the `AddressContainer` and the other is the presentational component Address.

The Address component is stateless however I need to set a value on a React-Select `async.Select` component that is part of the address component while updating another field via a redux dispatch - this works when its part of the one file however its not working now.

I need to move the following function to the container and reference the value...

```
         const onSuburbChange = (value) => {
          this.setState({ selectedSuburb: value }, () => {
            input.onChange(value)
            updatePostcodeValue(value ? value.postcode : null, sectionPrefix)
          })
        }
```

Since the markup has been moved to its own file and referenced in the container as:

```
   <Address handleSuburbSearch={this.handleSuburbSearch}
    addressData={addressData}
    updatePostcodeValue={updatePostcodeValue}
  />
```

I get the error

> address.jsx:100 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined
>       at Object.onSuburbChange [as onChange] (address.jsx:100)

Its clear to me that Address is stateless and that state is being/needs to be set in the AddressContainer..

Here is the React-select component thats in the presentational component - these are all props that it requires:

```
             <Select.Async
              {...inputProps}
              onChange={onSuburbChange}
              valueKey="id"
              labelKey="suburbName"
              loadOptions={handleSuburbSearch}
              backspaceRemoves={true}
            />
```

I would like to set the value of `onChange` in the addressContainer but I am unsure as to how rewrite `onSuburbChange` so it is passed the value and returns the value while also updating the postcode as per the other function `updatePostcodeValue`.

How do I move `onSuburbChange` to the container and reference it in the presentational component?

Comment: It should work if you replace `onChange={onSuburbChange}`by `onChange={onSuburbChange.bind(this)}`. This in javascript is dynamic and depends on how you call the function. If you bind it, you no longer have that problem. They speak about it here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html

Comment: Moved the function over to the AddressContainer - referenced onSuburbChange in Address and also in address container. its giving me the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: input is not defined". How do I reference input in the addressContainer?

Comment: Have you tried using `connect` to map the dispatch action to the container? https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md

Comment: @si2030, could you post your app.js file? Should be in your components folder. Also, instead of onChange={onSuburbChange.bind(this)}, try onChange={this.onSuburbChange} and let me know what you get. Although if you do it this way, it has to reference something to this effect: onSuburbChange(event) { console.log(event.target.value); this.setState({term: event.target.value}); }

Comment: @si2030, what I am trying to say is, the error is pretty clear. I don't know what the function of setState is. Well, your component if it only has one reference to setState, it should be defined, but you forgot to bind your context, especially in a callback. Rule of thumb, if you are ever passing a callback around onChange={this.onSuburbChange} and that callback has a reference to onSuburbChange(event) { this.setState({term: event.target.value}); } . You need to bind the context like this: this.onSuburbChange = this.onSuburbChange.bind(this);